# PostgreSQL request taking a lot of time to sum 30 columns

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I've an interesting case, I've been able to solve it but in a strange way.
Here's my request :

```
WITH geom_cte as (SELECT geom as geom)
SELECT SUM(number_a * percentage) AS number_a,
       ...
       SUM(number_b * percentage) AS number_b,
       SUM(number_z * percentage) AS number_z
FROM table_a AS A
JOIN (
  SELECT percentage, some_id
  FROM table_c, geom_cte
  WHERE postgis_indexed_condition
) AS B
ON B.some_id = A.some_id
```

There are 30 sums. This request takes 12s, which is a lot.
Here's the explain analyze : https://explain.depesz.com/s/L0aN

```
Aggregate  (cost=194.57..194.58 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=11997.284..11997.287 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=25409
  CTE cte
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..40.41 rows=17 width=3307) (actual time=0.354..247.066 rows=740 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=3368
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..25.68 rows=17 width=2325) (actual time=0.341..235.795 rows=740 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1145
              ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using forme_iris_geography_idx on forme_iris iris  (cost=0.28..25.64 rows=2 width=2293) (actual time=0.336..235.110 rows=740 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((geometry)::geography && cte.circle)
                    Filter: (_st_distance((geometry)::geography, cte.circle, '0'::double precision, false) < '1e-05'::double precision)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 97
                    Buffers: shared hit=1145
        ->  Index Scan using dl_rawdata_recensement_pkey on dl_rawdata_recensement population  (cost=0.29..0.87 rows=1 width=1002) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=740)
              Index Cond: ((iris)::text = (iris.code_iris)::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=2223
Planning Time: 1.677 ms
Execution Time: 11997.822 ms
```

It was quite strange because it take nearly a second to retrieve all the rows without the aggregation.
That's why I've decided to wrap the first result without aggregation in a cte and then aggregate in a second time. Surprisingly, the request now takes 700ms.

```
WITH geom_cte as (SELECT geom as geom),
data as (
SELECT number_a,
       number_b,
       ...
       number_z,
       percentage
FROM table_a AS A
JOIN (
  SELECT percentage, some_id
  FROM table_c, geom_cte
  WHERE postgis_indexed_condition
) AS B
ON B.some_id = A.some_id)
SELECT SUM(number_a * percentage) as number_a,
       SUM(number_b * percentage) as number_b,
       ...
       SUM(number_z * percentage) as number_z
FROM data
```

2nd explain analyze : https://explain.depesz.com/s/Z893

```
Aggregate  (cost=49.56..49.57 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=591.248..591.250 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4079
  CTE cte
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE data
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..45.26 rows=17 width=1010) (actual time=1.114..582.267 rows=740 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4079
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..25.68 rows=17 width=2325) (actual time=0.322..218.904 rows=740 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=1145
                ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                ->  Index Scan using forme_iris_geography_idx on forme_iris iris  (cost=0.28..25.64 rows=2 width=2293) (actual time=0.319..218.670 rows=740 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: ((geometry)::geography && cte.circle)
                      Filter: (_st_distance((geometry)::geography, cte.circle, '0'::double precision, false) < '1e-05'::double precision)
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 97
                      Buffers: shared hit=1145
          ->  Index Scan using dl_rawdata_recensement_pkey on dl_rawdata_recensement population  (cost=0.29..0.87 rows=1 width=1002) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=740)
                Index Cond: ((iris)::text = (iris.code_iris)::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=2223
  ->  CTE Scan on data  (cost=0.00..0.34 rows=17 width=1000) (actual time=1.117..583.875 rows=740 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4079
Planning Time: 1.021 ms
Execution Time: 591.435 ms
```

Any idea about why making the aggregation directly is that much costly ?

PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 11.16 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit

PostGIS version: 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: The queries does not seem to correspond with the plans, but a guess is that doing the join "first", minimizes the number of rows that has to be aggregated.

Comment: Is this timing completely reproducible, alternating back and forth between the ways of writing it?  In addition to the plans not matching the queries, that first plan just doesn't seem very credible as a reproducible thing.